# Difference between [border @ country] and [border /@ country]

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

I have a xml file and one line of the file is like this

```
<mondial>
      <country>
         <encompassed continent="europe" percentage="100"/>
      </country>
</mondial>
```

let say I want to select the country that encompasses continent is europe
so I wrote:

```
<result> {
 doc("mondial.xml")//country[encompassed @continent="europe"]//
city
 } </result>
```

But the answer says

```
<result> {
 doc("mondial.xml")//country[encompassed/ @continent="europe"]//
city
 } </result>
```

I thought if we use "/" right here we go to next directory in the file
could someone help me please? Explanation will be appreciated

Comment: Both of your XPath expressions are syntactically invalid.

Comment: No, the second one is valid. Perhaps you missed that it continues to a second line.

Comment: Your talk of "directories" and "files" suggests you are very confused, and that you haven't done any basic reading about XML or XPath, and are trying to work it all out by trial and error. That's not a good learning strategy.

Comment: @ Michael Kay Perhaps is invalid with XPath and is valid with XQuery –

Comment: @Win.ubuntu No, it is not. It is valid in XPath as well, it is even XPath 1.0

Comment: @ dirkk How?  XPath 1.0 doesn't support doc("..."). I'am using oXygen 17.0 and it tel me: "Can not find the function doc". and How about the tag <result> </result>? these tags are not valid in XPath.

Comment: @Win.ubuntu true; I was just thinking about the actual expression (starting with `//country`...). Still, then it simply is XPath 2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first example where you have `[encompassed @continent="europe"]` is invalid XPath.

Your second example is valid, although I would suggest removing the space in `[encompassed/ @continent="europe"]` as that is quite unusual.

In your second example, after the predicate you are trying to find the *self-or-descendant* `city` element, however this element does not exist in the XML provided. If your XML is correct then just change your second query to:

```
<result>{
    doc("mondial.xml")//country[encompassed/@continent = "europe"]
}</result>
```

You might also consider using `eq` instead of `=` here as you are doing an atomic comparison. However I will leave you to read about that. Priscialla Walmsley's XQuery book is an excellent resource if you are just getting started with XQuery.